# Log4J skipping logs in multithreading?

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to stress-test a utility which will be running an approximate 4,000,000 entries and heavily rely on logging each entry. I am using Log4J using a `RollingFileAppender` to log my entries onto disk.

The way I tackled this is by creating threads, each taking 2,000 entries. That amounts to roughly 200 threads.

The launcher is as follows:

```
public static int COUNT = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Sift Science Bulk");
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);

    for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {

        final Runnable uploader = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j=0; j<2000; j++) {
                    synchronized (logger) {
                        logger.info("test");
                        COUNT++;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        executor.execute(uploader);

    }

    executor.shutdown(); // Wait until all threads are finished. Just don't accept new threads.

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) { /*JUST ITERATE INDEFINITELY*/ }
    System.out.println(COUNT);

}
```

The end result is a little bit weird ...

- The `System.out.println` will print 4,000,000 as expected, but
- The file generated by log4j will ONLY have ~200,000 lines!

What am I missing?? Thanks guys.

Comment: Please post your Log4j configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. You guessed right-it was a configuration issue. The RollingFileAppender's `MaxBackupIndex` was set to 1, which was making sure it keeps just 1 backup file thus overwriting my previous entries!

The correct configuration is now as follows:

```
<appender name="appender1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="trace.log"/> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/> 

    <!-- FIX BELOW -->
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100000000"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <!-- FIX ABOVE -->

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

Thanks for the help just the same - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your log4j configuration too. The whole point of a RollingFileAppender is that when the logfile reaches a certain size, it gets moved to a backup. Check that you don't actually have several logfiles being generated each with 200,000 lines in them.